SQL Server selecting JSON attribute from a single array as multiple rows
Is there a way to select an attribute from a JSON document as multiple rows in the result? What I mean by this:
select JSON_VALUE(detailsColumn, '$.books[*].name') as Value
from authors
where id = '1234';

SQL server does not like *. I tried to use JSON_QUERY but it only returns if the query returns top level object or an array. I also tried to wrap JSON_VALUE((JSON_QUERY array), name) but I could not make it work either.
At the end I want to be to get result set that includes each 'name' in the array as a row item in the result set.

Do you mean select a.id, b.name from authors a CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(detailsColumn, '$.books') WITH (name VARCHAR(50)) b where a.id = '1234'?

i wanted to turm single json column on exactly one row into multiple rows of result set with only one column, in this example column is the name of the book. I was not  aware of "openjson with"  construct so i was able accomplish it with that similar to yours without using cross apply. Thanks!

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
